# Cannot login into Stack Exchange with Google account

Tags: support, login, google

When I'm logging in with my Google account, the website shows me a "Confirm and Create" new account button, but I want to log in as an existing user. (It works on the Android app.)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using the same Google account on your phone and the website?

Comment: Yes, i have only one Google account on phone and it is account, which i am using on computer

Comment: Did you compare the e-mail addresses? I've deleted all my Google and Stack??? cookies and webdata from my browser. After that I could login with my (correct) Google account again, and everything works fine.

Comment: Having the same issue.  If I login using an incognito window it works, but otherwise it will say that it is creating a new account,  Was this ever resolved?

Comment: This question is quite old and I do not have problems with it now. But it looks the issue is still here.

Answer (score 2):

Googling [how to remove cookies in Chrome](https://www.google.com/search?q=chrome%20remove%20cookies%20for%20a%20particular%20site), I got the following info:

## Delete specific cookies

1. On your computer, open Chrome.
2. At the top right, click More Settings.
3. At the bottom, click Advanced.
4. Under "Privacy and security," click Content settings.
5. Click Cookies See all cookies and site data.
6. At the top right, search for the website's name.
7. To the right of the site, click Remove .

At step 6, I put in `stackoverflow`.  After completing the steps, I was then able to login to SO again.  Had to do the same for my `stackexchange` accounts too.